# Limitar tamanho de uma String?

Tags: c, string

Declarei

```
char pl1[10], pl2[10];
```

E fiz o seguinte:

```
printf("Nome do Player1: ");
scanf("%10s", &pl1);
printf("Nome do Player2: ");
scanf("%10s", &pl2);
```

Pensando que ele ia ler só os 10 primeiros caracteres que o usuário digitasse. Porém assim, quando eu digito um  nome com mais de 10 caracteres o programa lê errado, exemplo, é digitado "dinamicamente", ele associa "dinamicame" á `pl1` e "nte" á `pl2`. Já tentei também sem o 10 no `scanf` daí ele armazena o que ultrapassou o escopo no `pl1`, exemplo (usando "dinamicamente") ele ignora o primeiro nome digitado (caso o segundo seja com mais de 10 caracteres), e atribui os 10 primeiros caracteres digitados quando pede o `Nome do Player 2` á `pl2` e o restante em `pl1`. Caso o digitado em `pl2` seja menor que 10 caracteres ele armazena o dinamicamente no `pl1` e o nome que foi digitado em `pl2`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pensei um pouco, tentei mas dava errado, mas hoje durante a aula me veio a ideia, cheguei em cada, tentei e deu certo. Primeiramente devemos alterar o valor dos vetores para um número que o usuário provavelmente nunca irá colocar como `100`. Após isso demos o `scanf`, e se o vetor tiver comprimento maior que 10 ele então em um while que apaga os caracteres até o elemento 10 do vetor:

```
int i;
char p1[100], p2[100];
printf("\nNome do Player1: ");
scanf("%s", &p1);
printf("Nome do Player2: ");
scanf("%s", &p2);

//Redefine tamanho do Nome do player1
i = strlen(p1);
if (i > 10){
    while(i != 9){
         p1[i] = 0;
         i --;
    }
}

//Redefine tamanho do Nome do player2
i = strlen(p2);
if (i > 10){
    while(i != 9){
         p2[i] = 0;
         i --;
    }
}
```

Essa foi a forma mais simples que achei sem ter de alterar o restante do programa.

Comment: "Primeiramente devemos alterar o valor dos vetores para um número que o usuário provavelmente nunca irá colocar como `100`." Uhoh! É assim que nascem os *buffer overflow*.

Answer (score 6):

Precisas de espaço para o `'\0'` e não podes por o `&` operador

```
scanf("%9s", pl1); // p1 = "dinamicam\x00"
```

mas o resto da string fica no buffer `// ente<ENTER>` e vai ser apanhado no `scanf()` seguinte

```
scanf("%9s", pl2); // pl2 = "ente\x00" e fica o <ENTER> pendurado no buffer
```

---

EDIT

Se quiseres cortar o input nos primeiros 9 caracteres e ignorar o resto, usa `fgets()`

```
fgets(p1, sizeof p1, stdin);
lenp1 = strlen(p1);
if (p1[lenp1 - 1] == '\n') {
    /* nome completo, com ENTER incluido */
    p1[--lenp1] = 0; // apagar o ENTER
} else {
    /* ENTER e possivelmente outros caracteres ficaram no buffer */
    int ch;
    do ch = getchar(); while (ch != '\n'); // limpa caracteres extra
}
```

<sup>[fgets a correr no ideone](https://ideone.com/EU4hgm)</sup>

Comment: Acho que seria melhor mudar o tamanho do vetor pra 11 ao invés de diminuir o número de caracteres lidos

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir aqui, ficou igual

Comment: No ideone passa-se o que eu descrevi: https://ideone.com/OlzRmU

Comment: Sim, esse é o erro que vem ocorrendo comigo, p1 tem "dinamicam"
p2 tem "ente" igual no seu exemplo

Comment: Mas se `p1` tem espaço para 9 caracteres mais o terminador ... não dá para lá meter `"dinamicamente"`!

Comment: Sim eu sei, só que ele não deveria atribuir o restante no outro vetor, e sim só ignorar esse restante, pois assim nao da pra informar o nome de p2, entende o problema agora? Tipo, é limitar o quento o usuário pode digitar

Comment: Para limitar o que o utilizador pode digitar enquanto o programa corre vais ter que usar funções especificas to teu Sistema Operativo. Ou usas uma biblioteca que torna isso mais ou menos fácil, por exemplo a [ncurses](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) ou [pdcurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDCurses) (em inglês).

Comment: Está dando certo quando eu coloco diretamente como a primeira coisa do programa, quando eu coloco dentro do case do menu ou if ele não funciona, ele pula a parte de p1

Comment: Misturar `fgets()` com `scanf()` é má ideia. Aparentemente o menu usa `scanf()` e deixa coisas penduradas no buffer. Muda esses `scanf()` para `fgets()` seguido de `sscanf()`.

Comment: Ele atrapalha o fgets() mesmo sendo número inteiro? Não sabia rs vou tentar aqui

Answer (score 3):

O problema é justamente o fato de que a função `scanf` não verifica se o tamanho da string lida "cabe" dentro da área reservada. Por isso, ao ler mais do que o alocado, a função continua escrevendo na memória. Como você declarou as duas variáveis uma seguida da outra, ocorre que ele acaba gravando na área da variável seguinte. Poderia ser bem pior, poderia invadir uma área de memória que não está reservada para o seu programa, causando erros de execução.

Se o seu compilador for da Microsoft*, há a função [`scanf_s`](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Scanf_s) que permite que você informe o número máximo de caracteres a ser lido (mais detalhes [nesta outra questão do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434735/difference-between-scanf-and-scanf-s)). Caso contrário, você precisa tomar o devido cuidado. Uma boa solução foi proposta [nesta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621973/2896619):

```
int scanner(const char *data, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char format[32];
    if (buflen == 0)
        return 0;
    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds", (int)(buflen-1));
    return sscanf(data, format, buffer);
}
```

Basicamente, você cria uma função própria (`scanner`) que recebe um parâmetro (`buflen`) com o tamanho máximo (e seguro) do seu buffer de leitura, e ela usa a função `snprintf` para criar a máscara com o tamanho desejado para o buffer e garantir que erros não ocorram.

<sup>* É importante observar [o comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68942/limitar-tamanho-de-uma-string/68947#comment140736_68947) do colega @pmg sobre o `scanf_s` ser uma função opcional para compiladores C, e não apenas algo exclusivo de compiladores da Microsoft.</sup>

Comment: o `scanf_s()` está descrito no [C Standard mais recente](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.2) mas faz parte do anexo K que é opcional para os compiladores.

Comment: @pmg Obrigado, não sabia. Sempre achei que era algo específico dos compiladores da Microsoft.